# I cannot install Team Explorer Everywhere (TEE) plug-in for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin, team-explorer, team-explorer-everywhere

I am using this guide http://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/tools/eclipse#_install-the-tee-plugin-for-eclipse to install **Team Explorer Everywhere (TEE) plug-in for Eclipse**, but when I added the name and location, I found the available software is **Azure Toolkit for Java** instead of **Team Explorer Everywhere**.

Is there any solution or alternative way to install TFS plugin for Eclipse?

**I am using Eclipse Oxygen, on macOS Sierra.**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Eclipse **Oxygen** there should be both **Azure Toolkit for Java**  & **Team Explorer Everywhere**.

[image]

[image]

---

You could try below solutions:

- Directly use `http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs` in
  **Location**.
- Download the latest version in
  [GitHub-team-explorer-everywhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases) and choose the way-- **install the plug-in from the update site archive**

Comment: Thank you so much @patrick-msft for your both solutions, first one did not work as well and do not know what is the reason, but second worked perfectly.